# Python iteration over non-sequence in an array with one value

Tags: python, list, iteration

I am writing a code to return the coordinates of a point in a list of points. The list of points class is defined as follows:

```
class Streamline:

## Constructor
#  @param ID     Streamline ID
#  @param Points list of points in a streamline
def __init__ ( self, ID, points):
    self.__ID           = ID
    self.__points        = points

## Get all Point coordinates
#  @return Matrix of Point coordinates
def get_point_coordinates ( self ):
    return np.array([point.get_coordinate() for point in self.__points])
```

With

```
class Point:
## Constructor
#  @param ID     Streamline ID
#  @param cor    List of Coordinates
#  @param vel    List of velocity vectors (2D)
def __init__ ( self, ID,  coord, veloc):
    self.__ID           = ID
    self.set_coordinate( coord )
    self.set_velocity( veloc )
```

The thing is that I start my code by defining a Streamline with one Point in the point list. A little down the road I call the function get_point_coordinates and the iteration over the list of points raises the following error:

```
return np.array([point.get_coordinate() for point in self.__points])
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence
```

I need to find a way to bypass this error and neatly return just a 1x2 matrix with the point coordinates.

I've had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871593/python-iteration-over-non-sequence) but it wasn't very helpful.

Comment: Then `self.__points` must not be an iterable. So what is the type of `self.__points`?

Comment: Post how you have instantiated the Streamline object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Either call the Streamline-constructor with a sequence instead of a single point: `sl = Streamline(ID, [first_point])`
2. Or ensure the constructor makes the single point to be iterable:

   ```
   class Streamline:
       def __init__ ( self, ID, first_point):
           self.__ID     = ID
           self.__points = [first_point]
   ```
3. It is a bad idea to write the constructor to accept a single point (`Streamline(ID, point1)`) and a sequence of points (`Streamline(ID, [point1, point2, ...])`). If you want so, you can do

   ```
   from collections import Iterable
   class Streamline:
       def __init__ ( self, ID, first_point):
           self.__ID     = ID
           self.__points = points if isinstance(points, Iterable) else [points]
   ```
4. Better than 3. would be to unpack the points given in arguments via `*` to enable `Streamline(ID, point1)` and `Streamline(ID, point1, point2, ...)`.

   ```
   class Streamline:
       def __init__ ( self, ID, *points):
           self.__ID     = ID
           self.__points = points
   ```