# iterating through a list of objects which is loaded by pickle

Tags: python, pickle

In a section of a game I am creating a user enters a username. The username and user's score are saved in an object which is pickled to an external file which has the other pickled score objects in it.

I then have a button on the UI that if clicked should display the Highest scores of all players in descending order.

I load in the file into a list with the code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229082/python-pickle-unpickle-a-list-to-from-a-file) .

```
Highscores = []
Highscores = pickle.load(open("Highscores.txt", "rb"))
```

I then use a bubble sort to sort the list of objects shown below.

```
def bubbleSort():
    swapOccured = True
    while swapOccured == True:
        swapOccured = False
        for i in Highscores:
            if Highscores[i].score > Highscores[i + 1].score:
                hold = Highscores[i + 1]
                Highscore[i + 1] = Highscores[i]
                Highscores[i] = Highscores[i + 1]
                swapOccured = True
```

The error that is getting returned is

```
for index in Highscores:
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence
```

I have looked at other questions like this for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871593/python-iteration-over-non-sequence)  but the error was that the program was looping through an object not looping through a list of objects. I'm pretty sure it's not the same error as the example, I think it could be with loading in a list of objects with pickle but I'm stuck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Defining Highscores as a list before you load the pickle doesn't change what the object is when it is loaded; it just overwrites the previous value. Clearly, whatever was saved in the pickle is not a list.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes. I think I am appending objects to the pickle like it was a list but it's not. This is the code I am using to dump it.
`currScore = calculateScore()`

`currUser = tkSimpleDialog.askstring("","Please enter a Username:")`

`newHighscore = scoreEntry(currScore, currUser)`

    `with open("Highscores.txt", "ab") as f:
        pickle.dump(newHighscore, f)`

Answer (score 3):

Just like `pickle.dump` dumps a single object to the file, `pickle.load` loads a single object from the file.  If you want a list, you will need to load them all:

```
with open("Highscores.txt", "rb") as score_file:
    Highscores = []
    while True:
        try:
            Highscores.append(pickle.load(score_file))
        except EOFError:
            break
```